I feed the mediaSource sourceBuffer with Uint8Arrays no errors but the video do not play. Why?
I have this web page (see code), the script runs without errors and the chunks are showed in the console as Uint8Arrays but the video do not show-up. On the server side the 13 .mp4 videos are present.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Video</title>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>My Video</h1>
            <video id="video" width="640" height="480" type="video/mp4" autoplay muted decoration></video>
      <script>
        'use strict';

        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        var i = 0;
        var url = "0.mp4";

        if (!window.MediaSource) {
            alert('The MediaSource API is not available on this platform');
        }

        var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        var sourceBuffer;

        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function() {
          sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4'); // ; codecs="h264"
          get(url, MyCallback);
        });

        function MyCallback(chunk)
        {
          console.log(chunk);
          sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(chunk);
          if (video.paused) {
            video.play(); // Start playing after 1st chunk is appended.
          }
          i++;
          if(i===14)
            i = 0;
            url = i.toString()+".mp4";
            get(url, MyCallback);
          }

          function get(url, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url, true);
            xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            xhr.send();

            xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status !== 200) {
              alert('Unexpected status code ' + xhr.status + ' for ' + url);
              return false;
            }
            callback(new Uint8Array(xhr.response));
          };
        }

      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

I did try to set the video scr= one of those mp4 and it was playing correctly, just to say the mp4 format seems good for firefox.

Make sure your file & code meets the following conditions:

Your MP4 video files need to be saved as a fragmented MP4 format (aka ISO-BMFF).A fragment can N frames, N seconds, N minutes, or whatever length you want.
Use a tool like FFmpeg, Handbrake or Bento to generate fragmented MP4s from your file.

Use the right codec for your MP4 video files. See my other answer for advice about it.



Effectively it was my mp4 files that were not correct. I got good results with this and webm format: ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -f rawvideo -s 640x480 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i ./ram/%d.yuv -c:v libvpx-vp9 -f webm ./ram/%d.webm. Thanks for your help!
